# Как сделать, чтобы программа запомнила выбор человека, чтобы использовать это в дальнейшем?

Tags: python

Решила попробовать написать текстовую игру, но столкнулась с одной проблемой.
Когда человек решает взять предмет, мне нужно, чтобы программа это запомнила, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было воспользоваться этим предметом (в том случае, если человек его выбрал). Если нет, то идёт другая команда с действием. Не могу это реализовать, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть много разных вариантов. Например, если такой предмет может быть только в единственном экземпляре, удобно использовать для хранения таких предметов коллекцию "множество":

```
items = set()

items.add('факел')
items.add('меч')

if 'меч' in items:
    kill_monsters()
else:
    flee()
```

А если одинаковых предметов может быть много, то можно использовать коллекцию "словарь":

```
items = dict()

items['золото'] = 100
items['бутерброды'] = 5

if health < 10:
    if items['бутерброды'] > 0:
        health += 100
        items['бутерброды'] -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то попробуйте присвоить в переменную значение взятое от `input()`.

И в дальнейшем обрабатывать условие отталкиваясь от переменной.

```
x = input()

if x == “yes”:
     print(“get yes”)

elif x ==“no”:
     print(“get no”)

else:
    print(“uncorrect answer”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Без контекста сложно ответить на ваш вопрос.
Однако, если вы пишете программу и вам нужно оставить выбор пользователя есть много способов сделать это.
Например, вы можете писать в текстовый файл. А затем прочитаете значения из текстового файла когда игра начинается.
Фреймворки разработки, такие как .Net включают компоненты для управления настройками.